# C# - .NET SOCKS 4/5 Support

Tags: c#, .net, socks

Is it possible to use Socks 4/5 as a Proxy with HttpWebRequest?
Im looking EVERYWHERE and cant find any helpful resources.

The reason im making this question is almost all other "Duplicates" have either no answers, or no useful answers, most refer to chilkat which doesnt help in my situation.

Comment: Willing to pay for support.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question, this is not freelancers site

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov May I know why?